# SQL SELECT Statement + Ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Well, this is a crud application which contains add/edit/delete options and I wanted to implement in order to add an other button to view a selected row but my query doesn't work, I am sending an http request with Ajax and am getting the data but the query doesn't work.

Form_view.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="dist/jquery.bootgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="dist/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jquery.bootgrid.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="">
        <h1></h1>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="well clearfix">
            <div class="pull-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="command-add" data-row-id="0">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Record</button></div></div>
        <table id="employee_grid" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped" width="60%" cellspacing="0" data-toggle="bootgrid">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">Empid</th>
                    <th data-column-id="employee_name">Name</th>
                    <th data-column-id="employee_salary">Salary</th>
                    <th data-column-id="employee_age">Age</th>
                    <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div id="add_model" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Employee</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" id="frm_add">
                <input type="hidden" value="add" name="action" id="action" >
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required></input>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="salary" class="control-label">Salary:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="salary" name="salary" required></input>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="salary" class="control-label">Age:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" required></input>
                  </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="edit_model" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Employee</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" id="frm_edit">
                <input type="hidden" value="edit" name="action" id="action">
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="edit_id" id="edit_id">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_name" name="edit_name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="salary" class="control-label">Salary:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_salary" name="edit_salary"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="salary" class="control-label">Age:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_age" name="edit_age"/>
                  </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="btn_edit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="view_model" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">View  Employee</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" id="frm_view">
                <input type="hidden" value="view" name="action" id="action">
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="view_id" id="view_id">


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="view_name" name="view_name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="salary" class="control-label">Salary:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="view_salary" name="view_salary"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="salary" class="control-label">Age:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="view_age" name="view_age"/>
                  </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="btn_view" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var grid = $("#employee_grid").bootgrid({
        ajax: true,
        rowSelect: true,
        post: function ()
        {
            /* To accumulate custom parameter with the request object */
            return {
                id: "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed"
            };
        },

        url: "response.php",
        formatters: {
                "commands": function(column, row)
                {
                    return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn-success btn-default command-edit\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></span></button> " + 
                        "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn-danger btn-default command-delete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></button> " +
                        "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn-warning btn-default command-view\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open\"></span></button>";
                }
            }
   }).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function()
{
    /* Executes after data is loaded and rendered */
    grid.find(".command-edit").on("click", function(e)
    {
        //alert("You pressed edit on row: " + $(this).data("row-id"));
            var ele =$(this).parent();
            var g_id = $(this).parent().siblings(':first').html();
            var g_name = $(this).parent().siblings(':nth-of-type(2)').html();
console.log(g_id);
                    console.log(g_name);

        //console.log(grid.data());//
        $('#edit_model').modal('show');
                    if($(this).data("row-id") >0) {

                                // collect the data
                                $('#edit_id').val(ele.siblings(':first').html()); // in case we're changing the key
                                $('#edit_name').val(ele.siblings(':nth-of-type(2)').html());
                                $('#edit_salary').val(ele.siblings(':nth-of-type(3)').html());
                                $('#edit_age').val(ele.siblings(':nth-of-type(4)').html());
                    } else {
                     alert('Now row selected! First select row, then click edit button');
                    }
    }).end()


    //View data 

    grid.find(".command-view").on("click", function(e)
    {
        //alert("You pressed edit on row: " + $(this).data("row-id"));
            var ele =$(this).parent();
            var g_id = $(this).parent().siblings(':first').html();
            var g_name = $(this).parent().siblings(':nth-of-type(2)').html();
            console.log(g_id);
                    console.log(g_name);

        //console.log(grid.data());//
        $('#view_model').modal('show');
                    if($(this).data("row-id") >0) {

                                // collect the data
                                $('#view_id').val(ele.siblings(':first').html()); // in case we're changing the key
                                $('#view_name').val(ele.siblings(':nth-of-type(2)').html());
                                $('#view_salary').val(ele.siblings(':nth-of-type(3)').html());
                                $('#view_age').val(ele.siblings(':nth-of-type(4)').html());
                    } else {
                     alert('error');
                    }
    }).end()

    //end view data


    grid.find(".command-delete").on("click", function(e)
    {

        var conf = confirm('Delete ' + $(this).data("row-id") + ' items?');
                    alert(conf);
                    if(conf){
                                $.post('response.php', { id: $(this).data("row-id"), action:'delete'}
                                    , function(){
                                        // when ajax returns (callback), 
                                        $("#employee_grid").bootgrid('reload');
                                }); 
                                //$(this).parent('tr').remove();
                                //$("#employee_grid").bootgrid('remove', $(this).data("row-id"))
                    }
    });
});

function ajaxAction(action) {
                data = $("#frm_"+action).serializeArray();
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",  
                  url: "response.php",  
                  data: data,
                  dataType: "json",       
                  success: function(response)  
                  {
                    $('#'+action+'_model').modal('hide');
                    $("#employee_grid").bootgrid('reload');
                  }   
                });
            }

            $( "#command-add" ).click(function() {
              $('#add_model').modal('show');
            });
            $( "#btn_add" ).click(function() {
              ajaxAction('add');
            });
            $( "#btn_edit" ).click(function() {
              ajaxAction('edit');
            });
            $( "#btn_view" ).click(function() {
              ajaxAction('view');
            });
});
</script>
```

response.php

```
<?php
    //include connection file 
    include_once("connection.php");

    $db = new dbObj();
    $connString =  $db->getConnstring();

    $params = $_REQUEST;

    $action = isset($params['action']) != '' ? $params['action'] : '';
    $empCls = new Employee($connString);

    switch($action) {
     case 'add':
        $empCls->insertEmployee($params);
     break;
     case 'view':
        $empCls->viewEmployee($params);
     break;
     case 'edit':
        $empCls->updateEmployee($params);
     break;
     case 'delete':
        $empCls->deleteEmployee($params);
     break;
     default:
     $empCls->getEmployees($params);
     return;
    }

    class Employee {
    protected $conn;
    protected $data = array();
    function __construct($connString) {
        $this->conn = $connString;
    }

    public function getEmployees($params) {

        $this->data = $this->getRecords($params);

        echo json_encode($this->data);
    }
    function insertEmployee($params) {
        $data = array();;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `employee` (employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age) VALUES('" . $params["name"] . "', '" . $params["salary"] . "','" . $params["age"] . "');  ";

        echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to insert employee data");

    }


    function getRecords($params) {
        $rp = isset($params['rowCount']) ? $params['rowCount'] : 10;

        if (isset($params['current'])) { $page  = $params['current']; } else { $page=1; };  
        $start_from = ($page-1) * $rp;

        $sql = $sqlRec = $sqlTot = $where = '';

        if( !empty($params['searchPhrase']) ) {   
            $where .=" WHERE ";
            $where .=" ( employee_name LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' ";    
            $where .=" OR employee_salary LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' ";

            $where .=" OR employee_age LIKE '".$params['searchPhrase']."%' )";
       }
       if( !empty($params['sort']) ) {  
            $where .=" ORDER By ".key($params['sort']) .' '.current($params['sort'])." ";
        }
       // getting total number records without any search
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` ";
        $sqlTot .= $sql;
        $sqlRec .= $sql;

        //concatenate search sql if value exist
        if(isset($where) && $where != '') {

            $sqlTot .= $where;
            $sqlRec .= $where;
        }
        if ($rp!=-1)
        $sqlRec .= " LIMIT ". $start_from .",".$rp;


        $qtot = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlTot) or die("error to fetch tot employees data");
        $queryRecords = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch employees data");

        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryRecords) ) { 
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $json_data = array(
            "current"            => intval($params['current']), 
            "rowCount"            => 10,            
            "total"    => intval($qtot->num_rows),
            "rows"            => $data   // total data array
            );

        return $json_data;
    }
    function updateEmployee($params) {
        $data = array();
        //print_R($_POST);die;
        $sql = "Update `employee` set employee_name = '" . $params["edit_name"] . "', employee_salary='" . $params["edit_salary"]."', employee_age='" . $params["edit_age"] . "' WHERE id='".$_POST["edit_id"]."'";

        echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to update employee data");
    }

    function viewEmployee($params) {
        $data = array();
        //print_R($_POST);die;
        $sql = "Select employee_name FROM employee WHERE id='".$params["id"]."'";

        echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to view employee data");
    }

    function deleteEmployee($params) {
        $data = array();
        //print_R($_POST);die;
        $sql = "delete from `employee` WHERE id='".$params["id"]."'";

        echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to delete employee data");
    }
}
?>
```

My query to view the data is :

```
function viewEmployee($params) {
        $data = array();
        //print_R($_POST);die;
        $sql = "Select employee_name FROM employee WHERE id='".$params["id"]."'";

        echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to view employee data");
    }
```

Any idea , what should I do to select data from database and print them in html form ?

Comment: Do you know if the AJAX executes succesfully?

Comment: Yes it's working fine , because the edit & delete options have no issue .

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong variable name from `$_REQUEST`, you are using `ìd` when you should use `view_id` as it is configured in the form hidden field.

Try

```
function viewEmployee($params) {
    $data = array();
    //print_R($_POST);die;
    $sql = "Select employee_name FROM employee WHERE id='".$params["view_id"]."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to view employee data");
    echo json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
}
```

Comment: I did that now , but still getting the same thing . my query : $sql = "Select employee_name FROM employee WHERE id='".$params["view_id"]."'"; but look when I click to the view button : http://www5.0zz0.com/2017/09/23/17/507700939.png                                  http://www5.0zz0.com/2017/09/23/17/508670784.png                                   I should get only the name .

Comment: Well , I think my query won't work because I didn't execute it yet , I copied the code from the update which collect the data and after clicking on the save button , the query will be executed . so my question is : how i could execute the select query and print the data in that popup . !

Comment: grid.find(".command-view").on("click", function(e)
    {
  
         return alert ('test');
     
    }).end()

Comment: Check out the new version. I forgot to use the fetch_all method of ```mysqli_result```